# wso2 samples not working

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

Been following the instructions at https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sending+a+Simple+Message+Through+the+ESB

And have successfully got the project to build (and deploy)

However, when I go to start the axis server as per the instructions I get the below

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\humphriesa>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_92

C:\Users\humphriesa>cd C:\wso2esb-4.9.0\samples\axis2Server

C:\wso2esb-4.9.0\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat
"Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
Using AXIS2_HOME:        C:\WSO2ES~1.0\samples\AXIS2S~1\
Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image

C:\wso2esb-4.9.0\samples\axis2Server>
```

Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the same problem reported [in this jira ticket](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4272). Try the solution given there and see. You'll have to edit the axis2server.bat file as explained in the jira comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since MaxPermSize JAVA option was removed in JDK 8, you have to change following

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -classpath "%SAMPLE_SERVERPATH%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\" %_SERVERNAME% %_HTTPPORT% %_HTTPSPORT% %_XDEBUG% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%AXIS2_ENDORSED%"  -Djar.class.paths=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dsystem.home="."  samples.util.Bootstrap  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" -conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml"
```

to

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -classpath "%SAMPLE_SERVERPATH%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%AXIS2_HOME%..\..\tmp\" %_SERVERNAME% %_HTTPPORT% %_HTTPSPORT% %_XDEBUG% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%AXIS2_ENDORSED%"  -Djar.class.paths=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dsystem.home="."  samples.util.Bootstrap  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" -conf "%AXIS2_HOME%repository\conf\axis2.xml"
```